# Difference in the order in which onclick events are triggered on mouse double click in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, events, gwt

We have used gwtext GridPanel in our GWT application to show data in tabular format. Whenever user clicks on any row then onRowClick and onRowDblClick events are triggered and below methods of Interface GridRowListener implemented in my class are called.

```
void onRowClick(Grid grid,int rowIndex, EventObject e)
{
 //do something
}

void onRowDblClick(Grid grid,int rowIndex,EventObject e)
{
 //do something
}
```

But, when a user double clicks through mouse, then the order in which this methods are called is different in IE11 and IE8.

**IE11 method call sequence**

1. onRowClick
2. onRowClick
3. onRowDblClick

**IE8 method call sequence**

1. onRowClick
2. onRowDblClick
3. onRowClick

I want the events in IE11 to be triggered in the same sequence as in IE8. Is there any possible workaround to fix this issue ?